# Rails: Skip logging backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am logging the errors of a rails application using exception_logger (https://github.com/ryancheung/exception_logger) and it is working file. But it is logging the backtrace which I don't want to be logged.

Is there any way to stop logging backtrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Side note: why would you want that? Backtraces are very valuable as they tell you exactly where a problem (exception) occurs in your code.*

Anyway, it seems that logging exceptions backtrace is not configurable in the `exception_logger` gem. So your only option would be to monkey-patch some of its code. I'd try to patch the setter for the backtrace in the [`LoggedException` model](https://github.com/ryancheung/exception_logger/blob/master/app/models/exception_logger/logged_exception.rb).

Put this into an initializer under `lib/initializers`:

```
# lib/initializers/logged_exception_patch.rb
module ExceptionLogger
 class LoggedException < ActiveRecord::Base
    def backtrace=(trace)
      write_attribute :backtrace, ""
    end
 end
end
```

This code will make the model just ignore back traces when saving the logged exceptions and save a blank string to the `backtrace` column instead.

But let me say again - I think that if you are logging real exceptions on a real site, sooner or later you will regret not logging the back traces because you will get an exception with an unclear origin...